# How to list file names from GoogleDrive in Listview (Android Studio)

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, google-drive-android-api, drive

the app can allready create files in the drive but what i allso need is, that all the created files are displayed in an ListView.
i would appreciate, if somebody has a code Example or some Links.
please excuse my english, i am very confused in the moment and have been looking for a solution the whole day...

This is a part of the MainActivity, as it is now:
saveFileToDrive() creates an XML File in an selected Drive Folder.
tagitems is the ArrayList.

```
 public void erstelleArray() {          //ArrayList, ArrayAdapter erstellt und mit ListView verbunden




        tagitems.add(0, "");
        tagitems.add(1, "");
        tagitems.add(2, "");
        tagitems.add(3, "");
        tagitems.add(4, "");
        tagitems.add(5, "");
        tagitems.add(6, "");
        tagitems.add(7, "");
        tagitems.add(8, "");
        tagitems.add(9, "");
        tagitems.add(10, "");
        tagitems.add(11,"");

        //ArrayAdapter erstellen
        ArrayAdapter<TagItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                                             R.layout.listview,  //gewähltes Layout
                                             tagitems);          //dargestellte Items


        //Listview mit Adapter verbinden
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

private void registerListViewClick(){         //überprüft, ob auf ein Element der ListView geklickt wurde, bei Klick auf ein Element wird ein AlertDialog geöffnet

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


            //Alert Dialog mit einem positive und einem negative Button. die Beschriftungen werden aus der strings.xml geladen
            AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);




            final EditText input;

            input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            myAlert.setView(input);

            myAlert.setMessage(R.string.alertDialog_message)


                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alertDialog_positiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    //der onClickListener für den PositveButton

                            String txt = input.getText().toString();


                                            saveFileToDrive(txt);
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bitte warten...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            tagitems.set(position, txt);

                            }
                        }
```

and this is the TagItem Class:

```
public class TagItem {

//Attribute
private String name;


//Konstruktor
public TagItem(String name){
    this.name =name;
}


//setter & getter
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Here is an sample code (https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesInFolderActivity.java) that illustrates how to list files in a folder. This would be a good starting point for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or you can even refer to this Google Official code if you want to just list out the files without the folder: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesActivity.java

Comment: @AniV I implemented the Code in my Project. The files are displayed. What kind of files are Displayed? it seems that only XML Files are in the Listview and they get listed two times.... allso interesting is, that if I delete the files, they are still displayed in the ListView, even if I reinstall the app      Thank you for your help and i hope you can answer my questions